# Is it possible to redirect stdout to two places in C?

Tags: c, unix, pipe, dup2

I've been stuck on this for a while now, is it possible to redirect stdout to two different places? I am writing my own shell for practice, and it can currently run commands like `ps aux | wc -l` or `ps aux | wc -l > output.file`. However, when I try to run `ps aux > file.out | wc -l`, the second command does not receive the input from the first.

In the last example, the first command would be run in a child process that would output to one end of the pipe. The logic is similar to what follows:

```
close(stdout);
dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

//If a file output is also found
filewriter = open(...);
dup2(filewriter, STDOUT_FILENO);

//Execute the command
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normal UNIX shells don't work with that syntax either.  UNIX (and some other OSs) provides the `tee`[1] command to send output to a file and also `stdout`.

Example:
`ps aux | tee file.out | wc -l`

[1] See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)

Comment: There is a related concept called a `named pipe` which can sometime be very useful as well, letting you create a special file which is the named pipe that can allow you to do some very useful things with interprocess communication.  If you care to read more about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe

Comment: Great, I'll take a look.

Comment: Interesting.  Never used it, always stuck with ksh since about 1992 (csh before that but not since, and bash once it became established as well) as most of the stuff I deal with is written in it.  I'll check it out.

Comment: Note that the `zsh` documentation says: _If the user tries to open a file descriptor for writing more than once, the shell opens the file descriptor as a pipe to a process that copies its input to all the specified outputs, similar to `tee`, …_ (and there's an analogous comment for multiple inputs and `cat`).  It's an interesting design, having the shell implicitly create extra processes.  Normally shells only create the process you specify.

Answer (score 2):

The `tee` command does just that in UNIX. To see how to do it in straight C, why not look at [tee's source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-170/tee/tee.c)?